# Tweak generation of IntelliJ configuration for building artifacts (derived from build.gradle)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Having a working setup to build my war-file using gradle, I'd like to tweak the generation of IntelliJ's own configuration for building artifacts (which is being derived from `build.gradle`) in a more persistent way.

For now, I am able to change IntelliJ's build configuration (for e.g. "Gradle : org.example.servlet : Servlet.war (exploded)") doing `Build` => `Build artifacts...` => `Edit...` as desired (in my case additionally adding the content of a certain directory to the exploded war). However, whenever "Refreshing the gradle project" or doing an "Import Changes" after e.g. applying a change to `build.gradle`, IntelliJ regenerates this configuration for building this artifact and my manual changes are lost.

This is expected, IntelliJ even warns about this (when making changes after clicking above `Edit...`).

Question: Is there a way to tweak the generation of IntelliJ's own configuration for building artifacts in such a way that the changes survive the mentioned refresh? Most likely by adding meta-information to `build.gradle`?

Looking around I came across [gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin) but was unable to set it to any use. If someone thinks, this is the way to go, please give an example of adding a folder's content to an artifact.

Comment: is there the `id 'idea'` in your plugins section in `build.gradle` ?

Comment: The only plugins being used atm are `io.spring.dependency-management` and `war`.

Comment: then try add `id 'idea'` in the plugins section. I've had other kinds of problems in gradle with idea that was simply corrected with that

Comment: How do you configure Gradle build file for these tweaks? You should not make any changes to IntelliJ IDEA configuration, change `build.gradle` instead so that you get the same results from IntelliJ IDEA build and from the command line Gradle build. If you want IntelliJ IDEA artifact to be different, you can make a copy of the existing artifact or add another artifact from scratch.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's exactly what I had in mind  (and stated in my question --- at least I thought so): Adjusting `build.gradle` so "Refreshing the gradle project" (inside IntelliJ) leads to the same IntelliJ artifacts as manually editing the artifacts by `Build` => `Build artifacts` => `Edit...`
Copying the existing artifact (using it as a template for my manual changes) doesn' work as it leads to an error, as long as the source artifact still exists. Deleting this source artifact doesn't help, as it will be re-created. Want me to dig up IntelliJ's error message?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached if the artifact produced by Gradle is different from the one generated by IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Your misunderstanding. I'm not claiming there exists an IntelliJ bug. I even said, that IntelliJ warns me about my approach (warning me about a possible future loss of my manual changes). I try to find a way to get to these manual changes by changing `build.gradle`, so they survive a "gradle refresh". Neither I´m talking about the final build artifact (i.e. the resulting war file) but the "IntelliJ thing" you may edit via `Build` => `Build artifacts` <== this "artifact"

Comment: There is no IntelliJ IDEA specific configuration for artifacts, you can't make Gradle configuration that will build one artifact via IntelliJ IDEA and another via the command line. The only way is to create the artifact manually in IntelliJ IDEA with some different name so that it doesn't clash with the automatically generated artifact name. Also if you don't reference the nick when commenting here, there will be no notification sent to the user (if more than one user has commented).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Slightly changed my wording as your comments didn't relate to my intented question. As for "There is no IntelliJ IDEA specific configuration for artifacts": I doubt it. When doing `Build`=> `Build artifacts` => `Edit...` (on Windows) there is an xml file being changed in `c:\Users\Hille\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\[...]`. I guess this build description is being used (unless you explcitly delegate building to gradle) when having a run configuration using e.g. an exploded war.

Comment: I was referring to Gradle file configuration, as the second part of the answer states you can customize artifacts per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder This gets slightly frustrating as I do know that I can "customize artifacts"; I've mentioned this four times in this thread, although not using "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S" (as in the document linked in your previous comment) but rather `Build` => `Build artifacts` => `Edit...`. Both leading to the same IntelliJ view. My question is: Is there a way to keep any customizations (or rather make these manual customizations obsolete) by providing another means (e.g. the mentioned gradle plugin) leading to the same customizations but "surviving a refresh" (as this currently resets customizations).

Comment: Yes, artifacts with the names not clashing with the automatically generated artifacts will persist after the gradle project refresh. IDE will read the configuration from the `.idea/artifacts` directory XML files. You can [share these files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) via the version control with the other users so that they don't have to repeat the artifact configuration steps.

Comment: @CrazyCoder If I copy one of the automatically generated artifacts and customize the copy, building the customized arifact (in IntelliJ) works as long as I deleted the automatically generated artifacts prior building. After doing a "Refresh", IntelliJ regenerates the artifacts and I get the error `Error:Cannot build artifact 'Gradle : org.example.servlet : Servlet.war (exploded)' because it is included into a circular dependency (artifact 'Gradle : org.example.servlet : Servlet.war (exploded)', artifact 'Local : org.example.servlet : Servlet.war (exploded)')` (cf. my 2nd comment)..

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce this behavior. I've never seen such an issue when creating an artifact manually. Might be specific to your project or artifact customizations.